Vertical line between buttons are not aligned in center
I would like to display a vertical line between my buttons and that it is centered between the buttons in the middle of the header however I have the line that goes up.
Also my disconnect button is not aligned.
Could you help me by respecting a responsive design?
Thank you

HTML
<div class='tabs'>
      <button mat-button>
        <span class='name'>A</span>
      </button>
      <mat-divider [vertical]="true" style="height: 10px; margin: 0 20px 0 10px; "></mat-divider>

      <button mat-button>
        <span class='name'>B</span>
      </button>
      <mat-divider [vertical]="true" style="height: 10px; margin: 0 20px 0 10px; "></mat-divider>

      <button mat-button >
        <span class='name'>C</span>
      </button>
      <mat-divider [vertical]="true" style="height: 10px; margin: 0 20px 0 10px; "></mat-divider>

      <button mat-flat-button class='density'>
          <span class='material-icons' style='transform: rotate(180deg)'>logout</span>
          <div class='name-logout'>Logout</div>
      </button>
    </div>

CSS
tabs {
    display: flex;
    font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;

    button {
      border: none;
      margin: 0 20px 0 10px;
      background: transparent;
      align-items: center;
      cursor: pointer;

      .name {
        color: white;
        font-size: 14px;
        line-height: normal;
      }

      .material-icons {
        background-color: white;
        color:#006AF5;
      }

      .name-logout {
        background-color: white;
        font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
        line-height: normal;
        text-size-adjust: auto;
        color:#006AF5;
      }
    }
    .mat-divider-vertical{
      height: 100%;
      align-items: center;
      background-color: white;
      width: 0px !important;
     position: inherit !important;
    }
  }


First of all, in your scss file missing . to define styles for class and not for tags. To align buttons and dividers to center you have to add align-items: center stylization to .tabs class in the .scss file.
SCSS:
.tabs {
    display: flex;
    font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
    align-items: center;

    button {
      border: none;
      margin: 0 20px 0 10px;
      background: transparent;
      align-items: center;
      cursor: pointer;

      .name {
        color: white;
        font-size: 14px;
        line-height: normal;
      }

      .material-icons {
        background-color: white;
        color:#006AF5;
      }

      .name-logout {
        background-color: white;
        font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
        line-height: normal;
        text-size-adjust: auto;
        color:#006AF5;
      }
    }
    .mat-divider-vertical{
      height: 100%;
      align-items: center;
      background-color: white;
      width: 0px !important;
     position: inherit !important;
    }
  }

